# Loop in Multidimensional arrays in angular and typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array, every item of this array has an object with some properties and two arrays:

```
           0:
           Attachments: []
           Content: "dfsdfsdfsd "
          ID: 15
           Messages:[
            0:
          ID: 23
          Message_Contant_ID: 15
          Recipient: null
          Recivie_DateTime: "2018-10-19T15:08:11.593"
          Seen_DateTime: null
          Sender: null
          User_From_Id: 96
          User_To_Id: 12
         ]
```

when I make ngfor in the template I can make a loop for the parent array and the Message array but I can't make an array for the attachments array.

the template :

```
<ion-list no-lines *ngFor = "let chat of chats; " >           
    <ion-item  text-wrap *ngFor = "let Message of chat.Messages;  " >

    <ion-avatar item-left    >
      <img src="../../assets/imgs/gonna.png" >
    </ion-avatar>


    <div class="bubble me"    >
      <h3>{{(chat)?.Contant}}</h3>
      <img id="photo"[src]="imgSrc" />
    </div>

    <ion-avatar item-right      >
      <img src="{{'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + publisherPic}}">
    </ion-avatar>

    <div class="bubble you"   >
      <h3> {{(chat)?.Contant}} </h3>
      <img id="photo"[src]="imgSrc" />
    </div>

  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I tried to make the attachments array in the component. But it does not work like the message array.

```
getAll(){
    this.ChatProvider.getMyData('senderId=' + this.puplisherId).then((data) => {
    this.responseData = data;
    console.log(this.responseData); 
    this.content.scrollToBottom();

    this.chats = this.responseData
    this.chatImage = this.responseData.Attatchments

    for (let i = 0; i < this.chats.length; i++) {
        console.log( this.chats[i]) 

        if (this.chats[i].Attatchments.length != 0 ) {
        this.photo = this.chats[i].Attatchments[0].FileData
        this.imgSrc = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.photo;

        for (let j = 0;j < this.chats[i].Attatchments.length; j++) {
            this.photo = this.chats[i].Attatchments[j].FileData
            this.imgSrc = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.photo;
        }
    }
}
```

How I can make this loop and make a loop for the messages array and attachments array?

Comment: `but I can't make an array for the attachments array.` - Are you saying: `<div *ngFor="let attachment of chat.Attachments">Test</div>` in your component HTML does not work? If so can you provide the error that is given in the console? Also please note that you have a typo: `Attachments` in your code.

Comment: in My code   ` <ion-list no-lines *ngFor = "let chat of chats; " > 
      <ion-item  text-wrap *ngFor = "let Message of chat.Messages;  " >
   `
you can see that I make ngfor for the parent array "chats" in parent container and the messages array in <ion-item> which child of <ion-list> because that when I make loop for attachments which is child of "chats"  as you mentioned It's work as a child of messages array

Comment: Not quite sure what that means but the issue is probably related to your code having `.Attachtments` all over rather then `.Attachments`.